# Docker and Volumes nocopy

Tags: docker, volume, mount

I want to mount a directory from my host to a Docker container, and I want to make some modifications inside the container. But, when I modify the content on the mounted point, the changes are also reflected on the host.

For example:

```
$ docker run -d --name webserver01 -v /home/guest/app:/app
```

After which I made some change inside the container in /app

```
$ docker exec -ti webserver01 'touch /app/test.txt'
```

The file test.txt is created on my host and inside the container (the idea is to only create the file inside the container)

I tried to use the flag `nocopy` but I have this error:

```
$ docker run -d --name webserver01 -v /home/guest/app:/app:nocopy
docker: Error response from daemon: Invalid bind mount spec "/home/guest/app:/app:nocopy": invalid mode: nocopy.
```

Docker version

```
$ docker --version
Docker version 1.11.1, build 5604cbe/1.11.1
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4):

There might be some way you can hide the file but with Docker volumes what you describe is not possible as the directory on the container is a mount of the directory on the host and not files being copied.

The `nocopy` modifier is for when you are creating a volume and data already exists in the container's path, you can specify if you want that data copied when the volume is created.

You probably need to design a volume structure so the file you are creating isn't on the shared volume.

Comment: I try another approach copying the files with the ADD command on the Dockerfile but the files are in different place than the Dockerfile and Docker don't allow this :(

Comment: Link to the `nocopy` official docs: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#long-syntax-3 for clarity.

Comment: Updated link to the `nocopy` docs in the compose specification: https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/spec.md#long-syntax-4

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but it might help people.

If you want to reflect modifications from the host to the container, but not the other way around, it will be hard.

If you want to get a "snapshot" of the code, you can get the code inside your container using COPY or ADD when building your image, which means that your code must be in the building context. For example :

```
.
├── content_to_mount
|   ├── stuff1.txt
|   └── stuff2.txt
├── docker_stuff
|   ├── docker.conf
|   └── Dockerfile
└── other_stuff
```

If you have that kind of file tree, you will need to build your docker image using something like the following command in the root directory (where you can see docker_stuff):

`docker build -f docker_stuff/Dockerfile .`

and in you Dockerfile, you would have something like :

```
COPY content_to_mount app
```

That can be "dangerous" if the code for your app is really in your home, because you shouldn't have too big a context for your docker build.

Another solution, but that would be a bit weird in the process, would be to mount stuff like so :

`$ docker run -d --name webserver01 -v /home/guest/app:/ref/app`

and have a specific entrypoint in your container that does a :

`cp -R /ref/app /app`

Then, you would have your reference code, the one mounted from the host, in `/ref/app` and the modifications you would run in `/app` wouldn't be reflected on the host.